# Create File inside jar folder

Tags: java, jar, file-handling

I have a jar file **abc.jar** 
which has some certain code to create a file inside  a folder named **temp** of same jar file. 
like

```
createFile()
```

Now i want to include **abc.jar** into my other web project. Which should call  this function **createFile()** and create file accordingly.

So is there any way to create file inside jar file.

I'm aware about jar which is always be compressed and read only. 
 But still is there a work around for the same, will be great help for me.

:)

Comment: What application feature are you trying to offer the user of the app.?

Answer (score 1):

For *reading* a file that is in `abc.jar`, you can use [`ClassLoader.getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29), but I don't think Java provides a similar facility for adding a file to a jar (for security purposes).

A jar file is simply a zip file, so if you really needed to, you could un-zip it to a temporary directory, add the file, and then re-create the jar with your new file in it.  However, I think this would not achieve the effect you're looking for - whatever file you added to the jar file in this manner would not be available to your running code, because the original jar (without the added file) was already loaded.

Comment: A jar file is a zip file, not a tar file. Its contents have a specified format. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format) for details. WAR, EAR and Apache AAR and MAR files are also ZIP files with their own stereotyped formats.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the complete Jar, add the file to the extracted directory structure and recreate the jar out of the directory structure.

You can use [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) and [ZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) for example to achieve this goal. Furthermore classes related to [ZipFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) and [ZipEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html) can be of help.

Directly adding a file is not possible as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at TrueVFS: http://truevfs.net/ (or its predecessor TrueZip https://christian-schlichtherle.bitbucket.io/truezip/). It provides a virtual file system access to archive files.